# How to add a product to cart by url for loggedin users?

Tags: url, prestashop, cart

To add a product to cart by URL you use:
http://www.yourdomain.de/shop/index.php?controller=cart&add=&id_product=166&qty=2

But this only works for guests. When you are logged in, you are redirected to the homepage.
I think there is a problem with the cookies maybe?

How to add a product to cart by url for loggedin users?

Prestashop v.1.5x

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is a post request. You can not give it by the url. may be you can try with jquery post request.

Comment: Hm, i just tried it: It also only works when you are not logged in :(

Comment: if you add the static token with the url then you can add the cart for the login user also. you will be have {$static_token} variable from the tpl file.

Comment: the url suppose to be "yourdomain.de/shop/index.php?controller=cart&add=&id_product=2&qty=2&token=450cfca40a80b5a0066c403eae89a203"

Comment: The static_token is only available at a prestashop page. where from I can geht the static_token from an external cms like wordpress? :-/